# Jquery Hide parent div when one of the span is empty

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs, and I would like to hide the first div because one of his span's child is empty. How can I do? 
Here is the structure of the html:

```
<div class="pricetag">1
    <div class="price">400</div>
    <span>hello</span>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">2
    <div class="price"></div>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">3
    <div class="price">250</div>
</div>
```

And I tried to do this:

```
   $('.pricetag span:empty').parent.hide();
```

Comment: `$('.pricetag span:empty').parent().hide();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parentheses in order to call the function since [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) is 
 just not a property. In your current code, it may throw error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined` since `parent` property is `undefined`.

```
$('.pricetag span:empty').parent().hide();
//                          ----^^----
```

```js
$('.pricetag span:empty').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricetag">1
  <div class="price">400</div>
  <span>hello</span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">2
  <div class="price"></div>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">3
  <div class="price">250</div>
</div>
```

---

Or you can use jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class selector of [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has) mothod.

```
$('.pricetag:has(span:empty)').hide();
```

```js
$('.pricetag:has(span:empty)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricetag">1
  <div class="price">400</div>
  <span>hello</span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">2
  <div class="price"></div>
</div>

<div class="pricetag">3
  <div class="price">250</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! But I have one more question, if it's not really empty but the span displays "null" how should i do?

Comment: something like <script> $('".pricetag span="null"').parent().hide();</script>

Comment: @Euph : `$('.pricetag').filter(function(){ return $('span', this).filter(function(){ return $(this).text().trim() === '' || $(this).text().trim() == 'null'; }).length; }).hide();`

Comment: @Euph : glad to hep :)